# Weak Interaction and Strangeness transformation

Tags: weak-interaction

Is there any processes involving weak interaction that preserve the strangeness for $S \neq 0$?

I can't find an answer to it on net or anywhere else, generally it is true that weak interaction changes strangeness by 1 unit.

Comment: Fixed that for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, your [PDG](http://pdg.lbl.gov/2018/listings/rpp2018-list-sigma-plus.pdf)   reminds you of the strangeness-conserving decays of 
$$
\Sigma^\pm \to \Lambda e^\pm \nu ,
$$
where the antineutrino is meant to accompany the electron, mutatis mutandis.

That is, either *uus* or *dds* decays to *uds* , with a very small branching ratio, since, as you are implying, the heavier *s* is much more likely to decay to a light quark. But, in these highly informative/insightful cases, it is a light quark that weak transmutes to its isopartner.

So it is not true that weak interactions need change strangeness.